# C# Export into Excel

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio-2005, export

I am having a simple C# windows-based application with crystal report viewer. I want to generate whatever contents in reports into Excel sheet with the same data and template. I made it happened, but it is having issues like, Images not exporting to Excel and also Report lines/boxes not showing, just only data is been generated. Please give me a sample or sample resource that I can get idea or reference links that has been explained.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably not the solution you are looking for, but it's worth noting that Excel can open HTML documents and read table structures and image URLs.

```
<html>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>a1</td>
        <td>a2</td>
        <td>a3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>b1</td>
        <td>b2</td>
        <td>b3</td>
        <td><img src='http://www.google.com/images/nav_logo99.png'></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</html>
```

Translates nicely into:

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/70057/screenshots/screen111229-063618.png